# unable to start tomcat server with liferay bundle

Tags: tomcat, liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

I have previously installed tomcat as windows service. I want to run now tomcat from liferay bundle. but when I am double-clicking `startup.bat` or `catalina.bat`, the window is closing just as it opens. I created `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable to give path till tomcat folder. Help me

Comment: can you check portal-setup-wizard.properties file? wrong value of liferay.home can lead to this issue.

Comment: where can i find this file. i tried searching this in complete folder

Comment: parallel to tomcat folder

Comment: i am sorry sir, but i have only data, license and tomcat-7.0.42 folders and these do not have any file names portal-setup-wizard.properties.   Yes, data folder has hsql folder containing lportal.properties file. its contents are "#HSQL Database Engine 2.1.0
#Wed Mar 19 11:44:32 PDT 2014
version=2.1.0
modified=no
"

Answer (score 1):

- Open command prompt.
- cd /bin
- catalina.bat start

It should display some JVM error here.

Set CATALINA_HOME folder till liferay-tomcat only.

Example value E:\liferay-portal-6.1.30-ee-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27

Comment: it shows "CATALINA_HOME environment not defined correctly. this environment variable is needed to run this program". I have created CATALINA_HOME environment variable and set path till bin folder inside tomcat-7.0.42 in it

Comment: i have tomcat installed as service in program files of windows and liferay-tomcat bundle in E: drive. Which tomcat folder should be specified in CATALINA_HOME variable @Haris

Comment: updated solution - use till tomcat only for CATALIAN_HOME. Don't worry about service. Just make sure that service not running when you run directly from command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Check your JRE_Home path is proper

Liferay portal folder/bin/setenv.bat 
Eg: **set "JRE_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jre7"** 
Note : Use latest JRE, Your command window will close automatically is your JRE version is old or incompatible. i use jre7 for tomcat 8. its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem(for liferay ce portal tomcat 7.4.0 ga1)

- If your system is 64 bit you should downlod 64 bit jdk version.
- Only set JAVA_HOME variable path(Don't need to add CATALINA_HOME or JRE_HOME).